# How to delete browser network log in java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, browser, webdriver

We have a requirement to perform some activity in browser and then capture the latest network log for chrome. I am trying to write a code where we can delete network log before performing a particular activity and then capture the log.

I am using this line of code for clearing the network log but it throwing a error: driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER).getAll().clear();

How I can solve this issue? Is there a alternative way to do in java for selenium framework?

Comment: by network log, you mean the http calls made by the application right?

Comment: That's right, Whenever we perform any task on browser then in network tab the log gets recorded with status.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt support in selenium to capture or delete the network calls made by the browser. To overcome this limitation, I have created a simple library [wow-xhr](https://github.com/sudharsan-selvaraj/wow-xhr) using which we can get the network calls made my the browser.

```
WowXHR wowXhr = new WowXHR(new ChromeDriver()); //any selenium webdriver or RemoteWebDriver
WebDriver driver = wowXhr.getMockDriver();

driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("selenium"); //enter value in search box
wowXHR.log().clear(); //clears all network calls
driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click(); //click search button

/* Get all network calls that are made after clicking search button */
List<XHRLog> logs = wowXHR.log().getXHRLogs();
logs.forEach(log -> {
    Date initiatedTime =  log.getInitiatedTime();
    Date completedTime =  log.getCompletedTime();

    String method = log.getRequest().getMethod().name(); // GET or POST or PUT etc
    String url = log.getRequest().getUrl();
    Integer status = log.getResponse().getStatus();
    String requestBody = (String) log.getRequest().getBody();
    String responseBody = (String) log.getResponse().getBody();
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = log.getRequest().getHeaders();
    Map<String, String> responseHeaders = 
    log.getResponse().getHeaders();
});
```